# Properties of the sum of two symmetrizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say you have two symmetrizable matrices, that is let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times L}$, be such that both $A=\Sigma_{A}D_{A}$,  $B=\Sigma_{B}D_{B}$, where $\Sigma{i}$ is symmetric and $D_{i}$ is diagonal. 
Now, I want to know if $C=A+B$ is also symmetrizable?
My first thought is that it is not in general unless $D_{A}=D_{B}$, $C=\Sigma_{A}D_{A}+\Sigma_{B}D_{B}$ which in fact is a sufficient condition. However, given that the decomposition is not unique I am not sure that this condition is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the answer is yes when $L\le2$. However, when $L\ge3$, the answer is no. Let $Z$ be the $(L-3)\times(L-3)$ zero matrix and
\begin{align}
C = (\widetilde{C}\oplus Z) &= \pmatrix{0&1&2\\ 1&0&3\\ 1&1&0\\ &&&Z}\\
&= \pmatrix{0&1&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 1&1&0\\ &&&Z}I
+\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&0&2\\ 1&2&0\\ &&&Z}\pmatrix{0\\ &0\\ &&1\\ &&&Z}.
\end{align}
Now, if $C$ is the product of a symmetric matrix and a diagonal matrix, then $\widetilde{C}=MD$ for some symmetric matrix $M$ and some diagonal matrix $D$. Since $\widetilde{C}$ is nonsingular, $D$ must be nonsingular too. Let $D^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(x,y,z)$. Then the condition that $M=\widetilde{C}D^{-1}$ is symmetric can be rewritten as the system of linear equations $x=y,\,x=2z$ and $y=3z$. Yet, this system clearly has no nontrivial solution.